# Can't unlock keychain from SSH

Tags: ssh, osx-el-capitan, keychain

I'm trying to unlock keychain from SSH, like:

```
security unlock-keychain -p password /Users/<user>/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

But the system keeps asking for user input on the other end.
This is OS X El Capitan.